# Why doesn't NASA publish amounts of awarded grants?

Tags: united-states, public-funding, nasa

Many US Government agencies including [DOE](https://science.osti.gov/Universities/sc-in-your-state/), [NIH](https://reporter.nih.gov/search/NX8PtT4BvUimQa1cWrgnpg/patents), [NSF](https://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch/download.jsp) and [CDMRP](https://cdmrp.health.mil/search.aspx) publish awarded grant amounts.  NASA does not, per attached reply from NASA on 06NOV23.

[image: NASA keeps grant amounts secret]

Why not?  What distinguishes NASA legally or functionally from these other scientific and defense-related US Government entities that allow it or give it a rationale to keep awarded grant amounts secret?

[DOD gives a clear public policy rationale](https://publicaccess.dtic.mil/search/#/pubdefense/simpleSearch) for publishing the grant information:

> DoD and ODNI/IARPA are providing the public with access to these
> documents in accordance with the Office of Science and Technology
> Policy (OSTP) memorandum, Increasing Access to the Results of
> Federally Funded Scientific Research, dated 22 February 2013 and
> Ensuring Free, Immediate, and Equitable Access to Federally Funded
> Research , dated 22 August 2022. DoDI 3200.12 DoD Scientific and
> Technical Information Program (STIP) and the DoD Grant and Agreement
> Regulations (DoDGARs) have been updated to include public access
> requirements.

Comment: Definitely on-topic here. You should probably delete the Acad Q though.

Comment: OK, will do...I guess it's a matter of self-discovery.  I got one downvote and 2 upvotes for 1 net upvote but it definitely seems like a topic that Academic stack exchange is not comfortable with.

Comment: @LarsEricson cool question, I've posted a link to it in [The Pod Bay](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9682/the-pod-bay), the chat room for Space Exploration SE. The primary reason that cross-posting (near-simultaneous, near-identical questions posted in more than one site) is always strongly discouraged is to prevent answer fragmentation. SE generates answers not only for the question author but for future readers and search engines, who don't always check all comments to find out if the question has additional answers elsewhere.

Comment: I used the data for a series of LinkedIn posts here: https://www.linkedin.com/newsletters/gptsplaining-7057513503103873024/ My alma mater was dunning me for contributions.  I told them they were better off pulling down grant money.  Then I decided to rank them based on US Govt grants in various categories.